# ExpressionEngine 3 module: create custom member field programmatically

Tags: members, ee3, module, database, query

I'm creating a custom member field programmatically. This works fine, except that I want the database column to be dynamic based on what's already in the database.

In my code below, the **uniqueFieldId** variable could be 2, or 5, or even 999. This should be based on the columns that are already in the database. When m_field_id_2 and m_field_id_3 exist in the database, **uniqueFieldId** should be 4 so that the function below adds the column m_field_id_4 to the database.

How can I do this?

```
private function create_custom_member_field()
{
    //ToDo: Find a way to calculate the columns, not the rows.
    $uniqueFieldId = ...;


    // Add new columns in the member_data table
    ee()->dbforge->add_column('member_data', array('m_field_id_' . $uniqueFieldId => array('type' => 'text')));
    ee()->dbforge->add_column('member_data', array('m_field_ft_' . $uniqueFieldId => array('type' => 'tinytext')));


    // Add the actual credits field
    ee()->db->insert('member_fields', array('m_field_id'    => $uniqueFieldId,
                                            'm_field_name'  => 'credits',
                                            'm_field_label' => 'Credits',
                                            'm_field_type'  => 'text'
                                            ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say this, But you are doing it wrong. You first need to add entry in **member_fields** table and then **member_data** table.

Like this: (I didn't tested the code)

```
// Add the actual credits field
$data = array(
    // 'm_field_id'    => $uniqueFieldId, (No need to pass this)
    'm_field_name'  => 'credits',
    'm_field_label' => 'Credits',
    'm_field_type'  => 'text'
);
ee()->db->insert('member_fields', $data);

/*Get ID of column to be set*/
ee()->db->select('m_field_id');
ee()->db->from('member_fields');
ee()->db->where('m_field_name', 'credits');
$id = ee()->db->get()->row('m_field_id');

// Add new columns in the member_data table
ee()->dbforge->add_column('member_data', array('m_field_id_' . $id => array('type' => 'text')));
ee()->dbforge->add_column('member_data', array('m_field_ft_' . $id => array('type' => 'tinytext')));
```

Comment: You're most welcome :)